# SQL Date and Time in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, dateadd

I need to use today's date in WHERE clause of a statement as 11:59 PM for today’s date. for eg. if today is 09/04/2018 then I want '09/04/2018 23:59'. I tried the following but didn't work:

```
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME

SET @today = DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1, DAY(GETDATE()) - 1) + ' 23:59:59'

PRINT @today
```

Please guide

Comment: Why would you want that?  Surely today is either `date = '2018-09-04 00:00'` or it is `datetime >= '2018-09-04 00:00' AND datetime < '2018-09-05 00:00'`?

Comment: in my WHERE clause I need - AND @today BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(10), Startdate, 101) AND ISNULL(StopDate, '06/06/2079'). So basically the data entered till 23:59 PM today has to considered. that is business requirement

Comment: Why are you converting the `startdate` column to a string before you check it?  What about cases with values of `startDate = '2018-09-04 01:00', stopDate = '2018-09-04 19:00'`? That range covers part of today but is not included by your suggested where clause.  If what you're looking for is `range that cover at least part of today` then more robust logic would be `WHERE startDate < '2018-09-05' AND (stopDate IS NULL OR stopDate > '2018-09-04')`  *(Note: I'm using `05` when check the start date - the range must start before the start of tomorrow, and end after the start of today.)*

Comment: One other consideration to watch: depending on your datatype and its precision, if you have a time of `23:59:59.999`, did that happen today or tomorrow?  _Technically_ with `datetime` (instead of `datetime2`) your data won't go into your database like that, but edge cases can get you if you don't use the correct precision. Other than that, you don't really want to build a sting to account for all of today. Just check for the part of today that is less than tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

If you like, you can do this with date arithmetic:

```
SET @today = dateadd(minute, -1, cast(dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date)) as smalldatetime));
```

I am concerned about trying to get the last minute of the day.  That suggests that you might be trying to use `between` or `<=` on datetimes.  Usually it is better to avoid constructs and use `<`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @t DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@t),MONTH(@t),DAY(@t),23,59,0,0);
```

**[DBFidde Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b56ba41b961827b1a8e135c2c38af4d2)**